# Jquery Galleria and Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-views, galleria

Alright, im probably doing something a bit stupid. Im developing in drupal 6, using views to get all images in nodes from the previous week. To put those images in a nice gallery, im using jquery Galleria, but instead of using the module im just using the javascript. Its working beautifully, but the only problem is, I need to link each image to its respective node. Does anyone know how to add a link to each image, can I do it in a text field over each image that dynamically changes? I don't think I can use a JSON array because I am using views results.

How do i change the views result to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the format Views is displaying the image in?

[image: Views Format]

There may be an "Image linked to node" option available (I am using the [ImageCache module](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache))